# Какой частью речи является слово ТОЛЬКО в предложении "Мы знаем только о существовании эфира"?

Tags: морфология

Какой частью речи является слово *только* предложении "Мы знаем только о существовании эфира"?

Answer (score 5):

В данном случае это **частица**, поскольку значение слова - "исключительно", "единственно". Вот общие правила, позволяющие разобраться:

http://russkiiyazyk.ru/chasti-rechi/k-kakoy-chasti-rechi-otnositsya-slovo-tolko.html

По стилю здесь больше подходит синонимичная частица "**лишь**" (она указывает на "самое малое" - преимущественно на ближайшее слово "существование", фокусируется на нём; общий смысл: "*что касается эфира, мы знаем только о его существовании*"), в то время как "**только**" по смыслу легко связывается с общим понятием "*существование эфира*" и создаётся ложное впечатление, будто "*мы знаем, что существует эфир, и больше не знаем ничего*".

Comment: Почему же — ничего? Просто, мы знаем только о существовании эфира, но этого недостаточно.

Comment: Потому что эта фраза исправляется от двусмысленности только добавлением контекста - сама по себе она неточна.